# How to Pass Specific Pair from Hibernate Many-to-Many Relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I am setting up a Many-to-Many relationship similar to the example here: https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-many-to-many-using-annotations-1.html.

If I want to create another entity called Grade that contains a specific Student-Course pair, how can I do that?  I know I can have Grade reference Student and Course individually, but that doesn't reference the STUDENT_COURSE table.  Ideally I would be able to have a StudentCourse object in my Grade class, but I don't know how to do that without creating a StudentCourse entity myself.

Comment: You probably want to break your ManyToMany into two OneToMany/ManyToOnes, with a new entity called Enrollment (representing a student enrolled in a course). Then Grade can reference an Enrollment.

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I figured, but I didn't know if there was an easier way to do it with Hibernate.